# Knokcout event handler for bootstrap date picker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have a Page that I have created with knockout, and can't seem to find any event handler for the bootstrap date picker, I have looked at some of the popular tools available such as [eyecon](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/), but can't seem to find a proper event handler that would data bind the Date value to my ViewModel. I have however found one that works with jQueryUi:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            //initialize datepicker with some optional options
            var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
            $(element).datepicker(options);

            //handle the field changing
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
                var observable = valueAccessor();
                observable($(element).datepicker("getDate"));
            });

            //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                $(element).datepicker("destroy");
            });

        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
                current = $(element).datepicker("getDate");

            if (value - current !== 0) {
                $(element).datepicker("setDate", value);
            }
        }
    };
```

But none for bootstrap. I have created this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fumunchu/HLVfA/) of my WebForm that I have Created with my Viewmodel. Any Advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working (minimal) version, using [bootstrap-datepicker.js](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/).  It should give you a starting point:

```
  ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                //initialize datepicker with some optional options
                var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
                $(element).datepicker(options).on("changeDate", function (ev) {
                    var observable = valueAccessor();
                    observable(ev.date);
                });
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                $(element).datepicker("setValue", value);
            }
        };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/HLVfA/6/